# Rails - How to create multiple records in a form based on which are checked?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a form which allows a User to select multiple contacts in which to share access to a Building the user created.

Here's a little context, which is not entirely required for understanding:

The database structure is that a User has multiple Buildings, a User has multiple UserConnections, and a UserConnection has multiple BuildingShares.  When a User wants to share a Building, they select which contacts and then submit their selection.  This creates a BuildingShare record for each user selected, which is a child of the User_connection between the User and the contact.

So, when a User wants to share a Building, they head to 'building_shares/share'.  The building_shares controller then loads up a list of that User's contacts:

```
class BuildingSharesController < ApplicationController

  def share
    @contacts = current_user.get_contacts
  end

  ...

end
```

I'm not sure how to structure the form view to create a Building_share record for each contact selected via a checkbox. If I could just somehow pair down the @contacts array to only include the contacts which were selected, then I can add this method to the BuildingSharesController:

```
def create_multiple
  @contacts.each do |contact|
    @user_connection = UserConnection.find(user_id: current_user.id, contact_id: @contact.id)
    @building_share = BuildingShare.find(user_connection_id: @user_connection.id, building_id: @building.id)
    if @building_share.nil?
      @building_share = BuildingShare.new(user_connection_id: @user_connection.id, building_id: @building.id)
      @building_share.save
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Sorry to be a non-answer, but I think [`fields_for`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for) has what you are looking for?